# How to combine if else with try except in python

Tags: python, if-statement, try-except

I have list of functions inside my class MyMatch and i am having indent error while combining the try except with the if else inside the function

**this is MyMatch Class**

```
class MyMatch(object):
    def __init__(self, match_id):
         self.followon = self._followon()

   def _followon(self):
      try:
          if self.match_json()['followon'] == '1':
              return True
      except:
          else:
              return False
```

**I am having indent error in the else block of followon function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `if/else` statement need to be inside a `try` section. I think that the best approach will be to do something like that:

```
class MyMatch(object):
    def __init__(self, match_id):
         self.followon = self._followon()

    def _followon(self):
       try:
           # Bellow code will return:
           # True when self.match_json()['followon'] == '1'
           # False when self.match_json()['followon'] != '1'
           return bool(self.match_json()['followon'] == '1')
       except KeyError:
           # This will return False when for example match_json()
           # does not have a 'followon' key
           return False
```

Comment: _Why you use try/catch in such simple check?_ The if statement could lead to a `KeyError`.

Comment: It rather questions to the author of this post wy he needs this `try/catch` at all? My answer for your question is more general: I don't know how `self.match_json()` is implemented so this construction will catch not only `KeyError` exception

Comment: Dont use bare except clause! If possible specify the expected exception (in this case mostly a `KeyError`, or at least restrict it to `Exception` (so you don't catch `SystemExit`) and by all means log the exception - else there's no way to find out what went wrong and why.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers agree but as I write above I don't know what to expect from `self.match_json()

Comment: @maQ as I wrote above, either only catch what you expect (here a KeyError) and let other exceptions propagate (so you have a cear feedback on which other exceptions can happen and decide which ones you want to catch and which ones you don't), or _at least_ catch `Exception` (which is not the same as using a bare except clause) and _log_ the exception (so you have a chance to find out if something unexpected happens).  I agree that there's not enough context to decide on the best strategy here, but most often the first one is the best as it avoids masking  unexpected critcal errors.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I totally agree.

Answer (score -1):

Your conditions should be inside the try block. Change it to this format

```
try:
    if self.match_json()['followon'] == '1':
          return True 
    else:
          return False
except:
    pass
```

Comment: 1. `if expression: return True else: return False` is much more simply expressed as `return bool(expression)`, 2. do NOT use bare except clause (I don't understand why this is still legal), and 3. the except clause should return `False`.